# Creating an order processing system from magento?

Tags: magento

I want to create a small order processing website, but in time I want the application to be able to extend to an e-commerce solution as well. So I decided to go with magento.

But I am not sure, if magento can be stripped down to only an order processing system. By order processing I want:

- Guests should be able select products
- Should be able to add products to cart
- But at last, instead of processing the order by payment system, the order should be forwarded to email of administrators, who will contact them individually.

How to configure Magento this way??

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Check out the Magento Connect website for extensions that allow you to do this. If there aren't any, you'll need to get a developer to help you if you aren't familiar with Magento.

Comment: @mrN: I think you are looking for [cart2quote](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cart2quote-2-0-customer-quotation-free.html) extension.

Comment: This is perfect and affordable solution https://magecomp.com/magento-email-cart.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is a full tutorial with all the files you will need, ready to download:

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-onestep-checkout-remove-payment-method-step

This does mark orders with the code 'free', however, you words are our servants and not our masters and you could change the word free to 'telesale' (or whatever):

> ...the basic idea of removing any step from checkout is to see a set a
>   default value for that step, so that magento order processing runs
>   smoothly. So when removing the payment method step, i have set the
>   payment method “Zero Subtotal Checkout” with code “free” as the
>   default payment method.

Answer (score 2):

If I got you well, you just want to avoid the CC processing,
In this case you can disable in Magento all payment systems except the 'Money/Check' one.

> 1. Guests should be able select products
> 2. Should be able to add products to cart
> 3. But at last, instead of processing the order by payment system, the order should be     forwarded to email of administrators, who will
>      contact them individually.

1. Magento offers you catalog/cart system by default ( mail is mandatory during order )
2. Magento offers you cart system by default
3. You can disable all payment system except 'Money/Check' one. (this will let user confirm their order without any check on the payment).
   Then you can contact all user checking the new orders in the backend ( user/guest email will be displayed along with the order display ) ...

**Settings**

- Add email notification for any new orders:

  1. Log in into admin area
  2. Go to `System->Configuration`
  3. In Sales section, click on `Sales Emails`
  4. Select the first section Orders.
  5. Enter your admin e-mail in the field “Send Order Email Copy To”.

Now You will receive a new mail every new order.

- Manage Payment Methods:
- Log in into admin area
- Go to `System->Configuration`
- In Sales section, click on `Payment Methods`
- Disable all except `Check / Money Orders`

Now your customer could order without any payment detail.

I think Magento should suit you, in case the 'Money/Check' payment system is not good for you, you will need to create a new module and add a new payment system.

I hope this helps you answer your doubt

Answer (score 2):

So, as I can understand, you want to finish customers work on the cart step. For example, by clicking Create an Order except Checkout.
Yes, you can use cart2quote or something like this.
The main idea is to save quote with quote items (from the session) after clicking Create an Order button. For example, you can get Quote and serialize it, get Quote items and also serealize them. When it is needed to show them to admin (in email or in admin section) - deserialize all info and display it. This will not be very easy, but is possible. May be it is better to customize some ready solution.